# Azure Powershell - How to get a subscription owner email?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azureportal

I'm trying to run `(Get-AzContext).Account.id` in a powershell runbook (through the azure portal), to get the email of the currently connected user.

The issue is that the value returned seems to be hidden for some reason. 
Here's an example of the kind of output I'm receiving "`d3f47515-0254-43tv-8060-c824e201088h`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not been hidden. I suppose you `Connect-AzAccount` with the `service principal` in the runbook, not the `user` account. The `d3f47515-0254-43tv-8060-c824e201088h` is the `Application ID` of the service principal.

To confirm this, just run `(Get-AzContext).Account.Type`, it will return `ServicePrincipal`.

[image]

If you logged in with a user account, it will return the `Userprincipal name`(i.e. email you want, note, strictly speaking it is different from email, but from your description, it should be the one you want)

[image]